# How to make your own 2D AABB collision system in unity?

Tags: unity, collision-detection, aabb

I can't use the built in unity 2d physics engine for my game, so I tried to make my own using the unity bounds.Intersects, that is working perfectly but my problem is that I don't know how to make the player stop when It collides. Ive tried multiple things like storing the players last position and "teleporting" it back to that position when it collides (That looks choppy). Ive also tried to invert the controls when your colliding (So like W makes the player go down, A makes it go right ect) but that is extremely buggy. How should I do it?

Comment: Can you give us more details why Unity's physics is unsuitable or unavailable in this case? This is a very unusual constraint, and might have other spillover effects that would be important for answers to take into account.

Comment: @DMGregory To use the physics system I have to use the velocity and addforce functions but In my situation I really do need to use the Translate function in order to get a smooth motion (Because anti-aliasing is turned of because its a pixel art game)

Comment: Ah, I thought it sounded like an XY problem. Solving the aliasing is going to be far easier than writing your own physics system, so I'd recommend asking a question about the aliasing issue instead. One straightforward way is to use non-rendered objects for all your physics, then position rendered objects using translate (and any rounding you might want) to copy the movements of their physical counterparts.

Comment: @DMGregory no thats not whats causing the choppiness. Whats causing it it the speed for example if I do translate (new Vector3(1,0,0)); The sprite would move 1 pixel every second but if I change the velocity to 1 its not moving 1 pixel per second. What I mean by this is that I do not have full control over the speed. So for example if the player is moving 0.346 pixels every second (With anti-aliasing off it will look choppy)

Comment: Comments aren't a great place for back-and-forth discussion. Would you be interested in continuing our discussion by chat? There are solutions to the problems that you describe, like physics interpolation, which are less drastic than writing a new collision system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to approach this. If all your collision shapes are AABBs, you could calculate the velocity, then snap to the nearest edge of the other box e.g. for a box moving right, you would set its x to other.bounds.min.x - box.bounds.extents.x to snap it.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, I don't know why you can't use the built-in physics, but you should consider using it. It's better for performances, and much easier.

if you need to make your own AABB collision system, you have to inform your script that handle moving the player.
you could do something like:

```
if(!YourCollisionObject.IsColliding()) {
    Move()
}
```

If there's no collision, your object is free to move, but if there is, your object won't move at all.

Comment: Well this dosen't work because if you collide you would have no way of getting away (You would be stuck basically)